# Responsiveness for mobile not working

Tags: html, reactjs, heroku, mobile

It was once not responsive so had to reconfigure to do figure it.

What could be the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="testTheme">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="icon" href="img\logo.ico">
    <title>Testing Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share your styles or some more code so that the issue you're seeing is reproducible? Or even pointing to your heroku deploy might be helpful.

Comment: @DrewSchuster Which styles are you referring to and to be honest, I'm stumped on how to reproduce it. Any specific leads and I can provide them. And what do you mean by pointing to Heroku deploy?

Comment: Like point us to the URL of your heroku deploy so we can see for ourselves

Comment: Rather, perhaps godaddy is wrapping your page in an iframe. If you have some sort of smart redirect happening within godaddy that's your issue

Comment: @DrewSchuster Thank you SO MUCH! Fixed it but before accepting the answer and upvoting, do you mind removing the link in the comments and answer? Let me know afterwards.

Comment: I deleted the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above comments, your issue is how you're redirecting your custom domain to your heroku deploy. See [heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) for a setup that will work for you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Answered and upvoted. One more question if you don't mind. How can I get my naked domain to work as well with GoDaddy and Heroku? For example, without www.